# Need help to extract file name and file url from string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the string

```
description = "----------------------------------------------\n\nTest Customer, May 11, 2023, 18:27\n\nDo you want to hear a construction joke? Oh, never mind, I'm still working on it!\n\nAttachment(s):\nistockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg - https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpgzendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json - https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json"
```

I would like to extract the file name and file URL from *Attachment(s)*.

The problem is the file URL is concatenated with the file name of the next file.

This is my current code:

```python
import re

description = "----------------------------------------------\n\nTest Customer, May 11, 2023, 18:27\n\nDo you want to hear a construction joke? Oh, never mind, I'm still working on it!\n\nAttachment(s):\nistockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg - https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpgzendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json - https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json"

# Extract the attachment section from the description
attachment_section = re.search(r'Attachment\(s\):\n(.+)', description, re.DOTALL).group(1)

# Extract the filenames and URLs using regular expressions
attachments = re.findall(r'([^\s]+)\s-\s(https?://\S+?(?=\s-\s\S+|$))', attachment_section)

# Process each attachment to extract the filename and URL
attachment_urls = []
for i in range(len(attachments)):
    file_name = attachments[i][0]
    url = attachments[i][1]
    attachment_urls.append({
        'file_name': file_name,
        'url': url
    })

# Print the extracted file names and URLs
for attachment in attachment_urls:
    print(f"File Name: {attachment['file_name']}")
    print(f"URL: {attachment['url']}")
    print()
```

My expected result is:

- File Name: istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg

URL:
https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg

- File Name: zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json

URL:
https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json

The attachment section can contain an unlimited number of files.

Would anyone be able to assist me with this issue? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the extension from the filename, and use a backreference to group 2 to match that in the url.

First check if group 1 exists, and then you can use for example re.finditer to use the capture group 1 and group 3 values.

```
(\S+(\.[^\s.]+))\s+-\s+(\S+?\2)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
  - `(\.[^\s.]+)` Capture **group 2**, match `.` and 1+ non whitespace chars other than a dot
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s+-\s+` Match `-` beteween 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `\S+?\2` Match 1+ non whitespace chars, as few as possible, and then match a backreference to what is captured in group 2
- `)` Close group 3

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlceLu/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/x03FDx).

```
import re

description = "----------------------------------------------\n\nTest Customer, May 11, 2023, 18:27\n\nDo you want to hear a construction joke? Oh, never mind, I'm still working on it!\n\nAttachment(s):\nistockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg - https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpgzendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json - https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json"

attachment_section = re.search(r'Attachment\(s\):\n(.+)', description, re.DOTALL)
attachment_urls = []
if attachment_section:
    matches = re.finditer(r"(\S+(\.[^\s.]+))\s+-\s+(\S+?\2)", attachment_section.group(1))
    for _, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        attachment_urls.append({
            'file_name': match.group(1),
            'url': match.group(3)
        })

for attachment in attachment_urls:
    print(f"File Name: {attachment['file_name']}")
    print(f"URL: {attachment['url']}")
    print()
```

Output

```
File Name: istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg
URL: https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg

File Name: zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json
URL: https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It helped me solve the issue I was facing. I really appreciate your assistance and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

A *simple/naïve* approach would be to harcode the file extensions :

```
f_exts = "jpg|json" #add here more extensions..
​
pat = fr"(\S+) - (\S+?\.(?:{f_exts}))"
attachments = re.findall(pat, description)
​
for file_name, url in attachments:
    print("File Name:", file_name)
    print("URL:", url, "\n")
```

> Regex [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/5t0JO4/1)]

​Output :

```
File Name: istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg
URL: https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=istockphoto-1131743616-612x612.jpg 

File Name: zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json
URL: https://aaa.zendesk.com/attachments/token/jIUzlZ4ylKke4iP0kB/?name=zendesk_tickets_20230511_091412058891.json
```